# EDAS Paper Submission Error

Tags: overleaf

I just submitted a paper on edas (INFOCOM 2023). As I uploaded the paper, there is one warning: page-empty. To be specific, page 10 is empty. However, in fact, page 10 includes all reference work. The code is as follows:

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}      
\bibliography{reference}
```

I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a file named "reference.bib" in the same overleaf that contains all information of BibTex. It seems no matter whether I use {reference} or {reference.bib}.

Comment: oh looking at https://edas.info/doc/authors.html you submit the pdf not tex source?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As per my experience, authors need to submit the PDF file on EDAS, not the tex file. However, the OP can clarify what he actually submitted.

Comment: The thing is that, Page 10 actually shows contents, which can be read by PDF reader. However, the edas system says Page 10 is empty. I have no idea which part of code causes  the error.